# Bootstrap 5 beta SCSS compiling error Invalid CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am getting the following error while compiling Bootstrap 5 beta SCSS.

> error scss/bootstrap-grid.scss (Line 6 of scss/mixins/_grid.scss:
> Invalid CSS after "...r-x: #{$gutter}": expected "{", was ";")

I have no idea what is wrong. What all I am doing is importing bootstrap main `scss` into my custom `scss`.

Even compiling `bootstrap.scss` without any custom stylesheet gives the same error.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see and understand your trying to compile the bootstrap `bootstrap-grid.scss`

Syntax of `bootstrap-grid.scss` is

```css
/*!
 * Bootstrap Grid v5.0.0-beta1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2020 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2020 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
 */

$include-column-box-sizing: true !default;

@import "functions";
@import "variables";

@import "mixins/lists";
@import "mixins/breakpoints";
@import "mixins/container";
@import "mixins/grid";
@import "mixins/utilities";

@import "vendor/rfs";

@import "containers";
@import "grid";

@import "utilities";
// Only use the utilities we need
// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$utilities: map-get-multiple(
  $utilities,
  (
    "display",
    "order",
    "flex",
    "flex-direction",
    "flex-grow",
    "flex-shrink",
    "flex-wrap",
    "justify-content",
    "align-items",
    "align-content",
    "align-self",
    "margin",
    "margin-x",
    "margin-y",
    "margin-top",
    "margin-end",
    "margin-bottom",
    "margin-start",
    "negative-margin",
    "negative-margin-x",
    "negative-margin-y",
    "negative-margin-top",
    "negative-margin-end",
    "negative-margin-bottom",
    "negative-margin-start",
    "padding",
    "padding-x",
    "padding-y",
    "padding-top",
    "padding-end",
    "padding-bottom",
    "padding-start",
  )
);

@import "utilities/api";
```

Make sure you have the same pattern as the above. If you face this problem again then download bootstrap v5.0 package again and try it out!

Answer (score 0):

This might have to do with using a **deprecated scss compiler**. Use [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) as stated in the [official Bootstrap 5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/build-tools/):

> Sass
>
> Bootstrap uses Dart Sass for compiling our Sass source files into CSS
> files (included in our build process), and we recommend you do the
> same if you’re compiling Sass using your own asset pipeline. We
> previously used Node Sass for Bootstrap v4, but LibSass and packages
> built on top of it, including Node Sass, are now deprecated.

The official documentation states to use [Dart Sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass). Whilst viewing this [equally named package on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass) it is labeled `deprecated`. Actually what is needed is the [Sass NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass).

### Angular V12 projects

refer to [this blog post](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49).

> Angular CDK and Angular Material have internally adopted Sass’s new
> module system. If your application uses Angular CDK or Angular
> Material, you’ll need to make sure you’ve switched from node-sass to
> the sass npm package. The node-sass…” — Mark Techson